# Excel formula to print all column headings where the cell is empty in a given range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://pasteboard.co/HVmsKpu.png This is what part of my sheet looks like.

I am trying to write a formula that will get the list of all Column headings `$G$1:$AE$1` where its corresponding cell values are blank.

So I wrote this formula after 30 minutes of Googling

```
=IF(COUNTA(DiscrepancyReport!G2:AE2)=0,"",INDEX(DiscrepancyReport!$G$1:$AE$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(DiscrepancyReport!G2:AE2="",0),0)))
```

It returns only the first row heading (10/29/2018).

How do I make this return all the column headings where the cell value is blank in that range (`G2:AE2`) delimited by a comma?

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 (or higher) or Office 365, you can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c).  Otherwise this will require VBA.

Comment: Thank you! I have Excel 2016. I will try this now and post back if I need help.

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(DiscrepancyReport!G2:AE2=0,DiscrepancyReport!$G$1:$AE$1,""))

I referred https://exceljet.net/formula/multiple-matches-in-comma-separated-list and used that syntax. It is returning #NAME? Should I be defining the range before using the formula? I will keep reading more but meanwhile I thought I will post here for guidance. Thank you!

Comment: @tigeravatar tagging you just so you will get notified. Thank you!

Comment: Give this a try: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(REPT(DiscrepancyReport!$G$1:$AE$1,DiscrepancyReport!G2:AE2<>""),))`

Comment: If the formula returns date serial numbers instead of the date datamask, use this formula: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(TEXT(REPT(DiscrepancyReport!$G$1:$AE$1,DiscrepancyReport!G2:AE2<>""),"m/d/yyyy"),))`

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind using a REPT function here? We are not repeating anything right? What we are trying to do is, say for example, Check headings from B1:H1 and if the cell value is blank (for say B10:H10) then we return the corresponding heading of the blank cells delimited by a comma. @tigeravatar

Comment: REPT will repeat text a number of times equal to the second argument.  In this case, the second argument is a boolean check to see if something exists in the current row.  If the check is `FALSE`, that gets translated to `0` so the header doesn't get written (REPT with 0 means a blank string), and if the check is `TRUE`, that gets translated to `1` so the header does get written.  This way it only writes the headers where the boolean check is true.

Comment: Great! Makes sense. So, I am using the second formula with date formatting and I can see it returns the correct dates in array list. However, the TEXTJOIN function throws an error on #VALUE on the first argument which is ", " Please see the screenshot here - https://pasteboard.co/HVvZXir.png @tigeravatar

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to replicate that behavior.  Formula works as expected for me :(

Comment: Ok :( I am using MS Office Professional Plus 2016. Not sure what is causing this error. I will keep looking. Thank you for your assistance :)